# How to copy/move files with more than two keywords

Tags: grep, copy

I have a file list like this (long list, not all):

[image]
And I want to filter the files with keywords "QM" and ".h5", so I type `ls|grep "QM"|grep "h5"` and it shows these (what I need)
[image]

So basically I want to move these files to another directory, but I don't know how to move them with one line of script.

Also, is there a way to randomly choose 5 of these files and copy them to another directory?

Comment: Shell globs (ex. `*QM*.h5`) are going to be your friends here

Comment: Thanks, it solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell globs are going to be your friends here.

For example, instead of using `grep`, you can list all files whose names contain `QM` and end with `.h5` using

```
ls *QM*.h5
```

You can use globs in `mv` and `cp` operations *provided that the number of matching files is not too large*

```
cp *QM*.h5 path/to/new_dir/
```

If the number of files is too large, you may get an `argument list too long` error; you can work around that using the shell's `printf` builtin with `xargs` to break the copy into manageable chunks:

```
printf '%s\0' *QM*.h5 | xargs -0 cp -t path/to/new_dir/
```

With bash, there's no intrinsic way to limit the number of files selected (or to select a random subset) but you could do so by adding a call to `shuf`:

```
printf '%s\0' *QM*.h5 | shuf -zn5 | xargs -0 cp -t path/to/new_dir/
```

Note that I used the null byte `\0` instead of the newline character to delimit the list of filenames - that's not necessary in your case, but makes the command usable in the more general case where filenames themselves may contain newlines.

If you don't mind switching to the z shell `zsh`, then you can select a random subset without resorting to external utilities, using the shell's more expressive *glob qualifiers*:

```
cp -t path/to/new_dir/ *QM*.h5(Nnoe['REPLY=$RANDOM'][1,5])        # zsh only
```

Related question on our Unix & Linux sister site:

- [How to pick a random file from a folder without repetition using bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553674/how-to-pick-a-random-file-from-a-folder-without-repetition-using-bash)

Answer (score 1):

"Many files"? "Files with funny characters in their name"?

This calls for `find` and `xargs`!

Read `man find;man xargs` and do something like:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*QM*.h5' -print0 |\
  xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty mv --target-directory=AnotherDirectory
```

Note: "`AnotherDirectory`" must already exist.

Note: See what the results will be by initaiily replacing "`mv`" with "`echo mv`".

Comment: it says ´mv: failed to access '~New_dir': No such file or directory´ . I created this New_dir

Comment: `~NewDir` refers to (nonexistent) user "`NewDir`""s HOME directory. Use `~/NewDir`.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the "New_dir", still it doesn't work. I guarantee that I mkdir the directory and it is properly referred.

Answer (score 0):

Just `cp *QM*.h5 target_dir`and done.

Comment: This doesn't answer the whole question, otherwise it is a duplicate of this existing answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1199883

Comment: And will NOT work if many (thousands) of files match. Been there, made that mistake.